# Running Nodemon in Docker Container

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, nodemon

I'm trying to run **Nodemon package** in a Docker Network with two services, NodeJs and MongoDB.

When I run the app with *npm start*, nodemon works: I can connect to **localhost:3000** and I have the changes in real time. But as soon as I run **npm run docker** (docker-compose up --build), I can connect to localhost:3000 but I'm not able to see real-time changes on my application nor console.

*docker-compose.yml*

```
    version: '3.7'
services:
  app:
    container_name: NodeJs
    build: .
    volumes:
      - "./app:/usr/src/app/app"
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
  mongo_db:
    container_name: MongoDB
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - mongo_db:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
volumes:
  mongo_db:
```

*dockerfile*

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /.
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "projectvintedapi",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js",
    "docker": "docker-compose up --build"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "mongodb": "^4.5.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it: it was for bind mount

*dockerfile*

```
FROM node:16.13.2
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY . ./
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
   version: '3.7'
    services:
      app:
        container_name: NodeJs
        build: .
        command: npm run dev
        volumes:
          - .:/app
        ports:
          - 3000:3000
      mongo_db:
        container_name: MongoDB
        image: mongo
        volumes:
          - mongo_db:/data/db
        ports:
          - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      mongo_db:
```

Answer (score 8):

`docker-compose.yml` tells Docker to boot a container, the Node.js application. It also tells Docker to mount a host volume:

```
    volumes:
      - "./app:/usr/src/app/app"
```

As a result, Docker will mount the ./app directory on your laptop, which contains your code, into the container at /usr/src/app/app.

Once you’ve changed your code on your laptop/desktop, nodemon detects that change and restarts the process without rebuilding the container. To make this happen, you need to tell Docker to set the entrypoint to nodemon. Do that in the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN npm install -g nodemon
RUN npm install

#Give the path of your endpoint
ENTRYPOINT ["nodemon", "/usr/src/app/server.js"]  
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

With host volumes and nodemon, your code sync is almost instantaneous.